# Angular2 app not working in IE with ES6, and compile errors with ES5

Tags: angular, ecmascript-5, typescript2.0

I have an angular2 application (2.0.0) using typescript (2.0.0).  In my tsconfig I compile to es6 with this line:

```
"target": "es6",
```

It works fine in Chrome and Edge, but it's not working in IE11.

I changed it to target es5 but then I get several compile errors such as:

```
ClientApp\app\services\tenant.service.ts(9,16): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
ClientApp\app\components\manage\users.component.ts(70,31): error TS2339: Property 'json' does not exist on type '{}'.
```

This does produce output and at runtime is seems to work in IE11 and the other browsers (but I have not tested everything).  I still don't like the compile errors.

I have core-js included.  I thought that was a fix for this issue.

Should I target 5 or 6?

Should es6 work in IE?  Is there a shim I'm missing?

How can I use es5 and get rid of the compile errors?

Here is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for the first error I think you should import the TypeScript definition https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/es6-promise/es6-promise.d.ts

For the second one, could you please paste the line code?

Comment: I had been using es6.  When I changed to es5 there are a lot of errors.  This is just a few.
I added the TS definition like this: /// <reference path="../../../../node_modules/es6-promise/es6-promise.d.ts" />  but still get the error.

Comment: with those TypeDefinition you still get the error on the Promise? with this too: /// <reference path="../node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts" />. At least the Promise error should gone after importing this TS definition.

Comment: I am seeing that I target es5 too but if I try to use Promise it imports from node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2015.promise.d.ts

Comment: When I use /// <reference path="../../../../node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2015.promise.d.ts" />  i get different compile errors that seems related to that library:

error TS2318: Cannot find global type 'Array'.
error TS2318: Cannot find global type 'Boolean'.
error TS2318: Cannot find global type 'Function'.

Comment: I 'fixed' the promise problem using declare var Promise - feels dirty.  I am down to one type of error: Property 'find' does not exist on type 'Tenant[]'.  I get this on several arrays.